# How to create a streaming HTTP Server in Crystal?

Tags: http, chunked-encoding, crystal-lang

I want to create a server similar to [Twitter Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview), so a client could read the response in real-time staying connected. How to do that in Crystal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Extracted from this [issue](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/5004):**

[@MakeNowJust](https://github.com/MakeNowJust) says:

> You should append `\n` to sent text to `gets` in client and do `io.flush`.

```
require "http/server"

port = 5000

server = HTTP::Server.new(port) do |context|
  loop do
    context.response.puts "Something\n"
    context.response.flush
    sleep 1
  end
end

puts "Listening on #{port}"
server.listen
```

[@rx14](https://github.com/RX14) says:

> crystal already handles writing chunked responses. Just keep on writing to the output response, and call flush when you want to ensure the client receives the message. If there is no content length header, the response will automatically select chunked encoding for you.